# How to filter text, removing lines where a specific position is empty

Tags: text-processing, grep, text-formatting

```
# lshw -c network -businfo
Bus info          Device      Class          Description
========================================================
pci@0000:03:00.0  enp3s0      network        I210 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:04:00.0  mec_test_1  network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:04:00.1  mec_test_2  network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:04:00.2  mec_test_3  network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:04:00.3  mec_test_4  network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:b5:00.0              network        Intel Corporation
pci@0000:b5:00.1              network        Intel Corporation
pci@0000:b5:00.2  mec_test_5  network        Intel Corporation
pci@0000:b5:00.3  enp181s0f3  network        Intel Corporation
```

If I want to pass Device is empty, how to do that?
like

```
Bus info          Device      Class          Description
========================================================
pci@0000:03:00.0  enp3s0      network        I210 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:04:00.0  mec_test_1  network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:04:00.1  mec_test_2  network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:04:00.2  mec_test_3  network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:04:00.3  mec_test_4  network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:b5:00.2  mec_test_5  network        Intel Corporation
pci@0000:b5:00.3  enp181s0f3  network        Intel Corporation
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to ask grep to look for a non-space character in the 19th column:

```
lshw -c network -businfo | grep -E '^.{18}[^ ]'
```

The `grep` command is looking for pattern that's anchored to the beginning of the line; there follows 18 of any character, then something that's not a space.

Alternatively, if there's a TAB there instead of space, use the `[:space:]` class:

```
lshw -c network -businfo | grep -E '^.{18}[^[:space:]]'
```

Comment: if I want to pass I350, how to do that? {18} just get char not string

Comment: I don't know what I350 is, here.

Comment: By "pass I350" do you mean omit those lines, or include only those lines? In either case, I think it would be appropriate to [Ask a new Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and refer back to this one as your starting point.

Comment: answer like this
Bus info          Device      Class          Description
========================================================

pci@0000:03:00.0  enp3s0      network        I210 Gigabit Network Connection

pci@0000:b5:00.2  mec_test_5  network        Intel Corporation

pci@0000:b5:00.3  enp181s0f3  network        Intel Corporation